# Iterate over images and then pause with button press using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It has been a very long time since I last looked at jQuery. I have the following markup

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div id="race_track">
    <%= image_tag 'race_track/track_curved.jpg', data: { engine: 'Sports'}  %>
    <%= image_tag 'race_track/track_hills.jpg', data: { engine: 'Hills'}  %>
    <%= image_tag 'race_track/track_rough.jpg', data: { engine: 'Rough'}  %>
    <%= image_tag 'race_track/track_straight.jpg', data: { engine: 'Straight'}  %>
  </div>
  <p class="lead"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Select</a></p>
</div>
```

What I am looking to achieve is have each image display one at a time and then when I click 'Select' the loop would stop on whichever image it was on at the time (though this can be random if needed).

I have had a look at the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) but the pause event only happens when you hover over the images and that's not what I was looking for.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: It has [option doc](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html), and it seems you can register the click event, and call `$('#slideshow').cycle('pause');` to pause it.

Comment: ah brilliant, that will definitely do, thanks

Comment: For own curiosity, I just created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oq3seuwu/2/), it seems work ;)

Comment: @fuyushimoya, I think this should be an answer rather than comment.

Comment: @fuyushimoya thanks for the fiddle, but not sure if it's me but I cant pause  it?

Comment: I changed in answer that use a button to pause it, @Richlewis would you check if it's working?

Comment: All working :-) Thank You

Comment: I guess it's because you need to focus on the jsfiddle's result block to make the `keyPress` event get captured, so change to `button`'s click event should be able to avoid the situation that we're not focusing on that block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jQuery Cycle Plugin Option Reference](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html), you can call its api to pause it like `$('#slideshow').cycle('pause');`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
  fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        timeout: 500
 });
  
    $('#start').on('click', function() {
        // Make it roll again
        $('.slideshow').cycle('resume');
    });
    $('#stop').on('click', function() {
        // Make it pause rolling.
        $('.slideshow').cycle('pause');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow" style="position: relative;">
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" spfieldtype="null" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 5; opacity: 0;">
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" spfieldtype="null" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 5; opacity: 0.0945702; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" spfieldtype="null" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 6; opacity: 0.904508; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" spfieldtype="null" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 2; opacity: 0;">
  <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" spfieldtype="null" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 1; opacity: 0;">
</div>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
```